# Pythonic way to construct a list filter

Tags: python

I have a function for filtering a list of dict based on the value of certain keys, like a `SELECT * WHERE xxx` query in SQL

```
list_of_dict = [
{'key1':val, 'key2':val},
{'key1':val, 'key2':val},
...
]

def filter_list(list_of_dict, key1, key2=None):
    if key2:
         filtered_list = [i for i in list_of_dict if i['key1']==key1 and i['key2']==key2]
    else:
         filtered_list = [i for i in list_of_dict if i['key1']==key1]
```

but when I have more keys as arguments to the function the `if ...else...` could go really long.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a large or variable number of keys, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to loop over them. Here's an example where the key values are provided as keyword arguments:

```py
def filter_dicts(dicts, **keys):
    return [
        d for d in dicts
        if all(d[k] == v for k, v in keys.items())
    ]
```

As @juanpa.arrivillaga points out, `dict_items` objects behave like sets in many regards, so you can alternatively filter for dictionaries which have `keys` as a subset:

```py
def filter_dicts(dicts, **keys):
    return [d for d in dicts if keys.items() <= d.items()]
```

Example:

```py
>>> dicts = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}]
>>> filter_dicts(dicts, x=1)
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}]
>>> filter_dicts(dicts, x=1, y=2)
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2}]
>>> filter_dicts(dicts, y=3)
[{'x': 1, 'y': 3}]
```

Comment: consider: `if keys.items() <= d.items()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did not know you could use a `dict_items` object in that way; if you post it as an answer I will upvote.

Comment: Eh, the crux of the answer is in using `**kwargs`. You can just add it as an alternative. I'm trying to up the awareness of dict view objects as set-like objects.